# phpMyAdmin 4.8.4 Authentication Application (2FA)

Tags: phpmyadmin, two-factor-authentication

I recently installed the new version of phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server and somehow I am unable to make 2fa work.

It used to work on 4.8.3 normally.

If I select 2fa and click on the "configure two-factor authentication" button I get the following error: [2FA error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBM4I.png)

But if I select the FIDO 2UF option I do not get any error messages.

I have run the command `composer require pragmarx/google2fa bacon/bacon-qr-code` as stated on the phpMyAdmin documentation for [two-factor authentication](https://cloud.riveramacias.com/rm-pma/doc/html/two_factor.html) and I am still unable to make it work.

Can any of you help me out figuring this out?

Comment: Anyone having this same issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have one quick question: In which folder do you install `composer require`? I am unable to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to work with FIDO 2UF but if I remove that and try with the authenticator method I get the same error as you.
I did need to do the manual method described at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables (basically importing two files) to get the hardware to work so worth trying that if you haven't already.